# Questionable Power Series for $1/x$ about $x=0$

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, integration, sequences-and-series, power-series

WolframAlpha states that

The power series for $1/x$ about $x=0$ is:

$$1/x = \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} (-1)^n(x-1)^n$$

This is supposedly *incorrect, isnt it?*

This is showing the power series about $x=1$ in the form $(x - c)$

I dont understand how WolFramalpha says that is correct:

http://m.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=power+series+of+1%2Fx&x=0&y=0

Thanks!

Comment: Yes. What you said.

Comment: Of course, one problem is that $\frac{1}{x}$ has no power series expansion with centre $0$.

Comment: So this is a power series but centered at $x =1$ wolframalpha is wrong?

Comment: then what is it?

Comment: So this is an invalid power series?

Comment: It's a completely valid power series for the domain $|x-1| < 1$. Obviously zero is excluded.

Comment: This is the power series for $1/x$ about $x=1$, not $x=0$ (that would be nonsense). Note the first term in the series is $1$, not $0$, so indeed the LHS = RHS at $x=1$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may recall that
$$
\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}r^n=\frac{1}{1-r},\quad |r|<1. \tag1
$$
Just substitute $r \rightarrow 1-x $ in $(1)$, you get, for the right hand side
$$
\frac{1}{1-r}=\frac{1}{1-(1-x)}=\frac 1 x
$$
as long as $|1-x|<1$ ($0$ being excluded).

Comment: But the question is what is the center?

Comment: @Amad27 Please, the center of what? Thanks

Comment: What is the power series about? In the form $a_n(x-c)$ the power series is about the center $x= c$, what is this "about?"

Comment: @Amad27 I see a power series expansion of $\frac1x$ around $x=1$. Isn't it?

Comment: Exactly, Wolframalpha returns it as the power series of $1/x$ about $x=0$ for some reason?

Comment: @Amad27 In your link to WolframAlpha, you did not mention the point $x_0$ for the power expansion, you've just written "power series of 1/x".

Comment: Even so, Wolfram is saying is about $x = 0$. This is clearly wrong, as it is about $x = 1$. In other words, this is another example of WA making a mistake. End of story.

Comment: Wow. WolFramalpha making a mistake, those are rare...

Answer (score 1):

It is rather strange, because Wolfram Alpha is perfectly happy to return a Laurent series for e.g.

[series of 1/(x+x^2) at x = 0](http://m.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=series%20of%20%201%2F%28x%20%2B%20x%5E2%29%20at%20x%3D0)

Somehow, $1/x$ is treated differently.

Comment: $1/x$ is its own Laurent series about the origin.

Comment: I know that, you know that, but does Wolfram Alpha?